# Does there exist a measurable function $f:S^1\to S^1$ whose Fourier coefficients never vanish?

Tags: real-analysis

If $S^1=\{z\in \Bbb C: |z|=1\}$, does there exist a function $f:S^1 \to S^1$ s.t. $\hat f(n) = \frac 1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})e^{-int}\text{d}t\neq 0$ for all $n\in \Bbb Z$?

I have tried using the Baire Category Thm. More specifically, let $V$ be the set of measurable functions from $S^1$ to $S^1$. Remark that $V\subset L^p(S^1)$ for all $p\ge 1$. If I let $K_n = \{f\in V: \hat f(n) = 0\}$, then $K_n$ is closed under both the $L^p$ and the uniform metric since $L^p$ convergence on a set of finite measure implies $L^1$ convergence, which in turn implies the existence of a pointwise convergent subsequence. If the claim is false, then $V=\bigcup K_n$, so the BCT shows some $K_n$ has nonempty interior. In other words, there is some $f\in V$ and $\delta>0$ s.t. $\hat f(n)=0$ and $||f-g||<\delta \Rightarrow \hat g(n)=0$ (where $||\cdot ||$ is either the $L^p$ or the uniform metric, to keep my options open).

My idea was to approximate $f$ by adding to it a tiny $\epsilon e^{int}$ term. If this approximation lies in $V$ and $||f-g||<\delta$, then we have a contradiction because $\hat g(n)=\epsilon$. A first candidate would be $g=f+\delta'e^{int}$ where $\delta'=\frac 12\min\{\delta,1\}$. Since $|g|\ge ||f|-\delta'|=|1-\delta'|>0$, I can normalize $G=g/|g|$, but then it may happen that $\hat G(n)=0$. Maybe I should be applying the BCT in some other way, but I cannot yet see it. Any hints?

Someone suggested in the comments to try $f(e^{it})=e^{i\sqrt 2t}$. I think $f(e^{it})=e^{it/2}$ should also work since 
$$\frac 1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{it(1/2-n)}\text{d}t=\frac{i(1-e^{\pi i-2\pi in})}{\pi -2\pi n}=\frac{2i}{\pi-2\pi n} $$
It seems to be that this function maps $S^1$ to $S^1$ and is measurable with non-zero coefficients, but now I am left to wonder why the problem statement gave the Baire Category Theorem hint. My best guess is that something is wrong with this example, but I have no clue of what.

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, I tried the obvious approach of constructing a Fourier series with nice coefficients, but I cannot constrain the resulting function's image to the unit circle.

Comment: @Lorenzo I added some paragraphs. I know I should be applying the Baire Category Thm, and the way I tried to do so seemed to most natural, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Dap it does seem to work. I have no idea why they would give such a hint in the problem statement when the answer was so simple.